# Error 13008, token has already been requested

Tags: office365, office-js, office-js-helpers

I am using Office.JS. I use getAccessTokenAsync to retrieve a token to exchange it for a resource token. But for some reason (I have this problem on Wi-Fi connection), I get the error code 13008 and message 'Please try that operation again after the current operation has finished.' telling me a token has already been requested. Since the token doesn't expire in the front-end, it is stuck in this function until I re-new the add-in which is not an option. This application will be used by clients later on.

There is very little documentation about this method and nothing on how to solve this as it seems nobody has this issue.

```
Office.context.auth.getAccessTokenAsync({forceConsent: false},
            function (result) {
                if (result.status === "succeeded") {
                    accessToken = result.value;
                    getDataWithPromise(apiURLsegment, accessToken, nameDocument)
                    .then(function(result) {
                            resolve(result)
                    })
                }
                else {
                    reject(result);
                    handleClientSideErrors(result);
                }
            });
```

When I call the method above, it instantly goes into the else statement as it does not let me request a new token. I'd like to find a solution for this problem. Preferably something that doesn't require re-adding the add-in.

Comment: This API is in Preview. Do not use it yet in an add-in that you ship to clients. You should not see this the first time that getAccessTokenAsync is called. Please provide the exact steps that lead up to the error.

Comment: @RickKirkham Do I only call this function once, until the token is expired? In the SSO-NodeJS example application, the function gets called every time a GET request is made. 

I don't really know how to replicate the error, but on a slow connection I click once, the function executes and before it is finished I click again and somehow it can get stuck in the first execute.

Comment: It is by design that getAccessTokenAsync is called with every GET. Office stores the token that it gets the first time, and then on subsequent executions, it simply returns the stored token. If the token is expired, it fetches a new one. If you call it a second time before it has fetched the token the previous call, the second call will fail with error 13008.

Comment: I understand the error. I have found a way to replicate it. I've put getAccessTokenAsync in a button function and I click it repeatedly. At one point, I get the error 13008 and it shows the error every time I click it, meaning the first operation hasn't finished. Even after waiting for a bit, it still gives me error 13008. Is there a way to cancel the first operation? Or maybe implement a time-out function?

Comment: You cannot cancel the call of getAccessTokenAsync. Can you disable the button until the first call completes?

Comment: @RickKirkhamI I have tried putting a 1-2 second disable timeout on the button, but it still eventuallly breaks after repeatedly calling the function. The same error pops-up again. 

I've tried to work around this by not calling the function with every GET, but instead calling it at the start of using the application and saving the ID token in a localStorage variable, and calling the function again when it expires. For some reason it does not give me a new token and goes to the else statement instead of having a 'succeeded' in status.

Comment: I don't think I understand the problem. Why are you calling the function repeatedly? Could you revise your question to provide step-by-step events/actions that lead up to the error?

Comment: @RickKirkham For testing/debugging purposes. Thus far, I have not found a way to work around error 13008 and the error breaks a crucial process. My question is: How do I solve error 13008 without refreshing the tab? To achieve error 13008, I simply have to call the function getAccessTokenAsync a couple of times. You stated in your earlier comment that getAccessTokenAsync is called with every GET. My application makes multiple GET requests and at random times, the call for the ID token hangs, does not give a result back, therefore giving error 13008 when called again.

Comment: I've tried working around this and not calling getAccessTokenAsync as much by making it a seperate function and making it check whether the token is expired or not. If so, request a new token with getAccessTokenAsync. But I've also noticed even when I barely touch the function, it sometimes simply does not always give me a result back resulting in error 13008 again. I'd like to take away the random factor of it breaking by solving this error. I can't call getAccessTokenAsync again, because it's already been called.

Comment: I still don't think I have a clear picture of what you are trying to do. What are you doing with the token? I can tell you that under-the-hood, the token you get with getAccessTokenAsync has an expiration that is no more than 1 hour. The first time you call it, it gets a token from Azure Active Directory. Office then caches that token. On any subsequent call of it, Office first checks to see if its expired. If not, it simply returns the same token again, else it goes back to AAD. You should not have to do your own caching/expiration checking.

Comment: "My application makes multiple GET requests and at random times, the call for the ID token hangs, does not give a result back, therefore giving error 13008 when called again." So this makes it sound like the 13008 is just a side effect of the hanging. Is that correct? If that's the case, then problem is the hanging, not the 13008, and you should retitle and rewrite the original question.

Comment: I realize that getAccessTokenAsync has an expiration functionality on itself, but the problem lies in the hanging of the function. When it does expire and it hangs, the application can't continue due to the error it keeps giving back. I can't reliably use it without it sometimes breaking. The problem is the hanging yes, but the biggest obstacle is error 13008, because it completely breaks the flow of the app. How the getAccessTokenAsync works lies beyond my app and code, that's why I'm asking the question for error 13008, to see if there's maybe a work-around for this problem.

Comment: The 13008 happens only in a browser and when a user didn't consent (i.e. he canceled consent window or admin consent is required, because it is the first time an app has been launched in his organization). The error will remain and an add-in won't be able to successfully complete calls of OfficeRuntime.auth.getAccessToken until a user restarts Outlook OWA (i.e. reloads outlook.office.com).